# Запятая перед "как"

Tags: пунктуация

...в таком предложении: "Иначе(,) как позорищем это не назовешь". Нужна тут запятая перед "как" или нет?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Конструкция *"не иначе как"* куда более распространенная, чем *"иначе как"*, но рассматриваются они одинаково.   
*"Иначе как"* - цельное по смыслу выражение, поэтому не разделяется запятой. Исключение - тот случай, когда на *"иначе"* падает логическое ударение, тогда запятая ставится. В вашем случае никакие ударения на *"иначе"* не падают, поэтому запятую не ставим.

Answer (score 0):

НЕ ИНАЧЕ КАК, цельное по смыслу выражение

То же, что «только, лишь, исключительно» или «наверняка, скорее всего». Между частями сочетания (перед словом «как») знак препинания не требуется.

Не верю я светской дружбе, еще менее светской любви; дружбе, которая ступает с гривны на гривну; любви, прилетающей не иначе как на бумажных крыльях из банковых билетов. А. Бестужев-Марлинский, Он был убит. 
Впрочем, если уж пить бургонское, то не иначе как Шамбертен номер тридцать восемь три четверти. А. Чехов, В вагоне. 
Не иначе как Губарев подряд в Питере взял: на всю аглицкую нацию мятные пряники поставлять. С. Черный, Солдатские сказки. 
«Не иначе как должны взять!» – еще уверенней отозвался боцман. С. Сергеев-Ценский, Флот и крепость. 
Голова болит – не иначе как простудился.

Comment: @ Если на слово «иначе» падает логическое ударение, то между частями выражения «не иначе как» ставится запятая: Луганович – это добряк, один из тех простодушных людей, которые крепко держатся мнения, что раз человек попал под суд, то, значит, он виноват, и что выражать сомнение в правильности приговора можно не иначе, как в законном порядке, на бумаге, но никак не за обедом и не в частном разговоре. А. Чехов, О любви. 
Д

Comment: ля него решительно ничего не значат все господа большой руки, живущие в Петербурге и Москве, проводящие время в обдумывании, что бы такое поесть завтра и какой бы обед сочинить на послезавтра, и принимающиеся за этот обед не иначе, как отправивши прежде в рот пилюлю; глотающие устерс, морских пауков и прочих чуд, а потом отправляющиеся в Карлсбад или на Кавказ.

Comment: НЕ ИНАЧЕ КАК 
____ 

Пунктуация при оборотах, не являющихся придаточными предложениями 

Цельные по смыслу выражения (§ 114, 2) 

Запятая не ставится внутри сочетаний не то что, не то чтобы, не так чтобы, не иначе как, например: Я его… не то чтоб любил, не то чтоб не любил, так как-то… (Тургенев); И не то что трое суток, и десятеро суток подождёте! (Л. Толстой); Сейчас здесь не то что раньше, всё стало интереснее; Время проводили не так чтобы уж очень весело;Заметка может быть набрана не иначе как петитом.